# método que reciba un dato entero(int) y determine si existe en un ArrayList

Tags: java, array, arraylist

Necesito un método que reciba un dato entero(int) y si es el primero se almacena y si no se compara con los demás para que este dato no se repita. Si existe devuelve un valor booleano (true)

```
//VALIDAR QUE NO SE REPITA EL CÓDIGO DEL PRODUCTO
static boolean codigoExistente(int codigo){
    boolean result = false;
    ArrayList<Integer> arrayCodigos = new ArrayList();
    if(arrayCodigos.size()>0){
        for(int i=0; i<arrayCodigos.size(); i++){
            if(codigo==arrayCodigos.get(i)){
                result = true;
            }else{
                arrayCodigos.add(codigo);
            }
        }
    }else{
        arrayCodigos.add(codigo);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Saludos. A simple vista, tu código siempre devolverá false; esto por que no guardas el int que recibes en una variable global, arrayCodigos está declarada en la función; por tanto siempre esta vacía.

Comment: Conviene que pongas la etiqueta del lenguaje con el que estás trabajando. Parece que es Java. En ese caso, podrías usar otro tipo de objeto que te facilite evitar duplicados por su propia naturaleza ahorrándote las comparaciones. [En esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17547360/5587982) y sus respuestas hay varias propuestas.

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio @Kim, el sitio no es para pedir còdigo , revisa [ask] y el [tour] , en realidad tu còdigo es casì correcto pero primeramente estas inicializando siempre el ArrayList dentro del mètodo codigoExistente() y nunca se quedaran almacenados los valores, saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu còdigo es casì correcto, pero tienes que sacar la declaraciòn del ArrayList donde se almacenaran los valores y no dentro del mètodo `codigoExistente()`, ya que si lo agregas dentro, el array siempre se estarìa inicializando, lo correcto es:

```
  private static ArrayList<Integer> arrayCodigos = new ArrayList();      
        
  static boolean codigoExistente(int codigo){
    ...
    ...
    ...
  }
```

De esta forma iteras sobre el array y si no existe el elemento lo agregas, si existe retornarìa un valor `true`:

```
private static ArrayList<Integer> arrayCodigos = new ArrayList();      
    
  static boolean codigoExistente(int codigo){
    boolean result = false;
    
        //Itera array para buscar si el còdigo existe.
        for(int i=0; i<arrayCodigos.size(); i++){
            if(codigo==arrayCodigos.get(i)){
                result = true;
            }
        }
        //Determina si no encontro el elemento en el array, lo agrega
        if(result == false){
           arrayCodigos.add(codigo);
        }   
      
    return result;
  }
```

Puedes probar tu mètodo, ejemplo:

```
 System.out.println("codigo 1 existente? : " + codigoExistente(1));
 System.out.println("codigo 2 existente? : " + codigoExistente(2));
 System.out.println("codigo 3 existente? : " + codigoExistente(3));
 System.out.println("codigo 1 existente? : " + codigoExistente(1));
 System.out.println("codigo 2 existente? : " + codigoExistente(2));     
 System.out.println("codigo 5 existente? : " + codigoExistente(5));
```

obtendrìas como salida:

```
codigo 1 existente? : false
codigo 2 existente? : false
codigo 3 existente? : false
codigo 1 existente? : true
codigo 2 existente? : true
codigo 5 existente? : false
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Jorge

Comment: Un placer, trata de revisar los documentos y mensajes que te comparte la comunidad, de esta forma obtendràs ayuda mejor y ràpidamente, un saludo y bienvenido al sitio!

Comment: Gracias pero es bienvenida jeje

Answer (score -1):

```js
public class Codigos {
    List<Integer> arrayCodigos;
    
    public Codigos() {
        arrayCodigos = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        codigoExistente(7);
        codigoExistente(4);
        codigoExistente(3);
        codigoExistente(7);
        codigoExistente(3);
        System.out.println(arrayCodigos);
    }
    
    //VALIDAR QUE NO SE REPITA EL CÓDIGO DEL PRODUCTO
    public boolean codigoExistente(int codigo){
        boolean result = false;
        if(arrayCodigos.size()>0){
            for(Integer c : arrayCodigos){
                if(c == codigo){
                    result = true;
                }
            }
            if(!result) {
                arrayCodigos.add(codigo);
            }
        }else{
            arrayCodigos.add(codigo);
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Codigos();

    }

}
```

Este código funciona bien. En el ejemplo se introducen 5 números (7,4,3,7,3), y después se visualiza la lista, que solo incluye el 7,4 y el 3.

Comment: Disculpa, los codigos del array se los debo debe de introducir el usuario, es decir, él introduce 4 y si el array está vacío se almacena este, de lo contrario se compara con los que ya tiene el array si encuentra uno igual devuelve un valor true, si no es igual a los que tiene el array este se almacena y así sucesivamente

Comment: Pues es eso precisamente lo que hace. Solo tendrías que recibir el numero introducido por el usuario y llamar a la función. En este caso no escribe en pantalla el true o false, pero eso lo podrías hacer con un print metiendo en el la función